# Trying to implement friendship between users. What kind of relationship do I need between the User model and the Friend model

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Currently I have a `Users` table and a `User` model. The `Users` table looks like this:

```
Table: Users
Columns: id, username, password, email
```

I assume if I want to implement friendship between users, I'd need to create a `Friend` model and `Friends` table which would contain the ids of the 2 users that have become friends

```
Table: Friends
Columns: id, userId, userId
```

Where both `userId` would be a foreign keys from the `Users` table. I'm using `Sequelize` ORM but I'm not sure what the relationship between the `User` and `Friend` models should be. I'm thinking `many-to-many` relationship but I'm a bit confused how to do it since both foreign keys are from the same table, therefore I need only 2 tables instead of 3.

Comment: one-to-many, but twice

Comment: @Shadow I see, and out of curiosity, are the 2 foreign keys that point to the same table allowed to have the same name? Should my friends table foreign keys be called userId/userId or userId1/userId2?

Comment: You cannot have the same column name more than one in a table.

Comment: Note that the surrogate id is somewhat redundant in this context. You have a plausible natural key on (initiator,reciprocator), although typically you'd want some way of confirming that reciprocation was complete. But there must be a million examples of this kind of thing out there.

Comment: Sequelize does not support composite primary/foreign keys